# What was the Cytherian describing in their introduction?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Near the end of the episode *The Nth Degree*, the Cytherian describes what they are seeing. To quote a transcript:

> ALIEN: Emotive. Electro-chemical stimulus response. Cranial plate, bipedal locomotion, endoskeletal. Contiguous external integument.
> PICARD: I'm Captain Jean-Luc Picard of the Federation Starship Enterprise.
> ALIEN: Hierarchical collective command structure.
> PICARD: Who are you?
> ALIEN: Interrogative.

The clip can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaKrMf3WTOM). Watching the scene, it is not clear to me where the Cytherian is looking at, what they are describing with each line, and what that means in plain English. Can anyone match up each utterance to something that was happening or seen on the chip during the clip?

Comment: I feel like this could be answered with a dictionary.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is basically just "*say what you see*". He's looking at Worf moving.

> Worf quickly moves to position himself between it and Picard, pulling his phaser.
>
> **ALIEN:** (re: Worf's action) *Emotive. Electro-chemical stimulus-response. (a beat) Cranial plate.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Nth Degree - Screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/193.txt)</sup></sub>

So, what he's saying is that Worf is displaying [actions based on emotion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emotive), that his [nervous system is electro-chemical and responsive to his surroundings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nervous_system) and that he's got [a big forehead](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cranial_ridge).

> Picard puts out a hand, holding Worf off. Worf stops.
>
> **ALIEN:** Bipedal locomotion. Endoskeletal. Contiguous external integument.

He's still looking at Worf here. He's saying that he [walks on two feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipedalism), has [a skeleton inside his body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoskeleton) and [skin all around the outside of him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integumentary_system).

> PICARD: I am Jean-Luc Picard, Captain of the Federation Starship Enterprise.
>
> ALIEN: (aha!) Hierarchical collective command structure!

Picard demonstrates that the ship operates in a [top-down society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy) with [him above Worf](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chain_of_command). Note that at this point the Cytherian recognises that Picard is the more interesting person in this exchange.

> PICARD: Who are you?
>
> ALIEN: (still describing what it sees) Interrogative.

Picard demonstrates that [we ask a lot of questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative).

Comment: I wonder how the Cytherian would describe Armus or Nagilum!

Comment: @HamSandwich - Emergent, no external integument, malevolent.

Comment: I would even describe it as akin to someone describing like, a group of ants they are studying: 

Exoskeleton, six legs, Antennae. 
Cooperative, navigate by scent. 
*Gets bitten* Aggresive! Venomous?

Comment: @CérylWiltink That reminds me of a [great Babylon 5 scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLZW8Deq8vE).

Answer (score 3):

The Cytherian is describing to itself aloud, the humanoids it is seeing, in very technical terms.

Emotive -> feeling emotions
Electro-chemical stimulus response -> nervous system
Cranial plate -> skull
bipedal locomotion -> walks upright on two legs
endoskeletal -> internal skeleton, not external like an insect
Contiguous external integument -> skin
Hierarchical collective command structure -> describing Starfleet
Interrogative -> asks questions

Comment: I believe the cranial plate he's referring to is Worf's big forehead, not just his skull

Answer (score -2):

The last answers are the closest, I believe. The Cytherian is describing humanoids. At first I wondered if he might be referring to Worf. Possibly with “Emotive.” But since they’re so different from humanoids I don’t think it’s likely he would distinguish between humans and Klingons. The terms he uses to describe them indicate he is very different - ie, endoskeleton, cranial plate,contiguous external integument - skeleton inside, skull and covered in skin.

I have to say I find this episode really interesting. First, seeing Barclay change and grow so much. Then ending with first contact with such an interesting alien!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This only seems to cover the first line that the Cyntherian says; what about the rest?  Can you improve this to explain why the Cyntherian is talking about the crew in general rather than Worf in particular?

Comment: This also doesn't add anything to the existing answers. Note, too, that referring to "last answers" is a bit nebulous here - answers can be sorted in different orders by different users, and even if you're referring to "latest" in chronological order, _your_ answer is now the latest...